# How to Maintain Persistence State of a Dropdown with JavaScript Disabled - PHP

Tags: php, javascript, drop-down-menu, persistence

I am working on some form coding in PHP, and I have everything working pretty well when JavaScript is enabled.  But from past experience and poor experiences with other sites not doing well when JavaScript is disabled, I thought I would pay more attention to it for this current project.

Regarding `input type="text"` POST fields, this is not a problem.  But for the drop-down I happen to be using, I cannot get it to persist.  Well, I can, but then the default selection is not correct.  Here is some code...

Basic drop-down structure:

```
<select id="topic" name="topic">
    <option value="Select an option">Select an option</option>
    <option value="Topic A">Topic A</option>
    <option value="Topic B">Topic B</option>
    <option value="Topic C">Topic C</option>
</select>
```

I thought maybe if I blended `selected` with POST data, I could get it to work like this:

```
<select id="topic" name="topic">
    <option selected="selected" value="Select an option">Select an option</option>
    <option value=""><?php echo $_POST['topic']; ?></option>
    <option value="Topic A">Topic A</option>
    <option value="Topic B">Topic B</option>
    <option value="Topic C">Topic C</option>
</select>
```

But it doesn't persist; it only goes back to the default, 'Select an option'.

Trying this didn't work either:

```
<select id="topic" name="topic">
    <option value="Select an option">Select an option</option>
    <option selected="selected" value=""><?php echo $_POST['topic']; ?></option>
    <option value="Topic A">Topic A</option>
    <option value="Topic B">Topic B</option>
    <option value="Topic C">Topic C</option>
</select>
```

It persists, but doesn't have the correct default.  Starts out blank (because POST is not entered yet).

I have done some Google searches and not really found anything very useful for this kind of thing, so I'm not sure where to go next.  Any ideas/suggestions?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: store the user selection in a session, check the session to set the  option as selected.

Comment: possible duplicate of [default value of dropdown on webpage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4625373/default-value-of-dropdown-on-webpage)

Comment: I will check the potential duplicate.  Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I normally do something like the following:

```
<select id="topic" name="topic">
<option value="Select an option">Select an option</option>
<?php
    $topics=Array("Topic A","Topic B","Topic C");
    foreach($topics as $topic){
        echo '<option value="'.$topic.'"'.($_POST['topic']==$topic?' selected="selected"':'').'>'.$topic.'</option>';
    }
?>
</select>
```

What this does is print out the select box just as you've described, but it adds a selected="selected" attribute to the option that matches your $_POST variable.

Comment: Thanks for the trick.  I like the alternate syntax version too.

Comment: One quick question.  It seems that even though viewing source shows the expected output, the drop-down seems to be behaving oddly, like it shows blank after validation fail, or it shows the array item before the one it should be...  Any idea why this might be?

Comment: Nevermind.  I figured it out.  I had pulled apart the if statement into non-alternate syntax to get a better idea of the exact process, and I forgot to add the closing `</option>` tag.  Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php 
$topic='';
if isset($_POST)
  if is_array($_POST)
    if isset($_POST['topic'])
      $topic=$_POST['topic'];
?>

<select id="topic" name="topic">
    <option value="Select an option">Select an option</option>
    <option value="Topic A"<?php if($topic=='Topic A') echo ' selected="selected"'; ?>>Topic A</option>
    <option value="Topic B"<?php if($topic=='Topic B') echo ' selected="selected"'; ?>>Topic B</option>
    <option value="Topic C"<?php if($topic=='Topic C') echo ' selected="selected"'; ?>>Topic C</option>
</select>
```